# How to format Android xml in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring

The GUI designer for Android in Eclipse spits out this type of XML (into a layout):

`<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnSaveMessage" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right" android:text="@string/text_save" android:width="125dp"></Button>`

Is there a refactoring in Eclipse to turn this goo into pretty formatted XML like this:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveMessage" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:text="@string/text_save" 
        android:width="125dp"/>
```

Comment: Select all cntrl+A then press cntrl+I

Comment: @hotveryspicy It almost does the job - that is it formats the XML for the size of my screen.  I'd like it to place a single attribute per line, rather than 2 or 3 that your technique does.

Comment: update your SDK, then it will do

Comment: Make sure you are using ADT plugin 14.0 or higher. It should format xml automatically (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: @hotveryspicy, That did the trick.  Thanks a bunch - it is literally exactly what I needed.

Comment: formatting != refactoring :) don't abuse the term!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

or

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this.

For doing so follow the steps

1. Select the source code in xml file.
2. Right click on selected source code.
3. Now go the Source->cleanup document.
4. Now a cleanup window is popup, mark check for appropriate options and click ok.

you can also choose source->format to do some formatting in xml. cleanup provide some other fuctionalites besides format.

[image: Cleanup window]